# angular-oauth2-oidc implementation is (falsely) throwing a CORS error

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, angular-oauth2-oidc

I'm trying to implement angular-oauth2-oidc Authentication in my angular app. On server side everything is configured correctly (also CORS).

My configuration looks like this:

```
    this.oauthService.configure(authCodeFlowConfig);
    this.oauthService.setStorage(localStorage);
    this.oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh();
    this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new NullValidationHandler();
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin().then(() => {
       console.log('Discovery document fetched successfully');
    });
```

My URL looks like this:

```
https://some-identity-provider.com/OAuth/Authorize?client_id=xxxxxx&p=my_policy&redirect_uri=' + window.location.origin + '&scope=openid%20profile&response_type=id_token
```

This URL definitely works. When I open it directly in the browser, it correctly redirects me to the login page.

However, in my application, it tries to redirect me to the login page, but I'm getting a CORS error:
[image]

When I look at the parameters, it seems to append `/.well-known/openid-configuration` to the last parameter.

[image]

Somehow it seems to mix up the URL and its query parameters...

Can anybody please help?

Comment: You're not showing the full code to reproduce the issue, so we need to guess a little bit at the root cause unfortunately. Did you perhaps configure the library with the query string inside the `issuer`? The library needs the "naked" issuer and be allowed to append the `.well-known` stuff for some requests, and do the query string itself for others. See for example [this way I tend to configure things](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/master/src/app/core/auth-config.ts).

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, meanwhile I figured it out. It was exactly what you pointed out: I've added the URL (with it's query parameters). But in order to fetch the `.well-known`, it needs to be without the query parameter. 
This was something which kept me up for a long time (my mistake). However, this could also be highlighted more prominently in the docs to save others from that.

Comment: Cheers! You could consider writing it up as an answer to your own question, for others to see more clearly than a comment? Cheers anyways, glad you fixed it!

Comment: Please update with your solution. I am having the exact same issue and would love to know how you fixed this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some of you asked, let me post how I solved this issue:

The problem was in my `AuthConfig`:

```
export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
    // Url of the Identity Provider
    // The problem was here: What I had before (caused the bug):
    issuer: 'https://some-identity-provieder.com/.well-known',

    // What fixed the issue is: Providing only the base url here:
    // The lib takes care of appending all parameters if needed.
    issuer: 'https://some-identity-provieder.com',

    // URL of the SPA to redirect the user to after login
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,

    // The SPA's id. The SPA is registerd with this id at the auth-server
    // clientId: 'server.code',
    clientId: environment.clientId,

    responseType: 'code',

    logoutUrl: 'some-logout-page.com',

    scope: `openid profile offline_access ${environment.clientId}`,

    showDebugInformation: environment.isLocalEnvironment,

    // turn off validation that discovery document endpoints start with the issuer url defined above
    // https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/additional-documentation/using-an-id-provider-that-fails-discovery-document-validation.html
    strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
    skipIssuerCheck: true,
};
```

Please see the `issuer`.
Also check all other parameters. This is my working config.

It's worth to mention to provide the `clientId` in the scope, because only then you get an `id_token`.

Hope this helps :)